# Installing graph-tool into Enthought Canopy (OS X 10.10)?

Tags: enthought, canopy, graph-tool

I am trying to install graph-tool into Enthought Canopy.

Has anyone had success doing so? If so, can you provide your steps?

Comment: The website has install instructions: https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/features/#package_manager

Comment: That's only for packages pre-built in the Enthought repo, which graph-tool is not yet. (There's only an old version in the deprecated, unsupported "Community" repo.) So the user is probably looking for actual build instructions.

Comment: Yes exactly, there are the build instructions and since pip or easy_install don't work, the install choices seem to be homebrew or macports. I am uncertain as to how either will work with Canopy